# Projection ETRS89 (Ellipsoid: GRS80) 6-Degree Zone 33 to UTM33N - WGS84

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, proj

I'm having trouble to reproject a shape file in Qgis.

The projection is supposed to be "ETRS89 (Ellipsoid: GRS80) 6-Degree Zone 33" and I would like to project it to **UTM33N - WGS84 (EPSG 32633)**.
When I set the Layer CRS to EPSG 25833 or EPSG 4258 and save it as UTM33N-WGS84 I don't get the result as intended...

This is the file I would like to reproject:
http://www.projektidee.org/images/extern/landschaftsschutz.zip

It should fit to this area in the end:
http://www.projektidee.org/images/extern/gebiet_UTM33.dbf.zip

Maybe one of you could give me a hint what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, screw the ordnance survey of Mecklenburg-Vorpommern (and Brandenburg for that matter). They decided to go with their own custom CRS which add a leading 3 or 33 to the easting value (must remind them of their beloved Gauß-Krüger coordinates I suppose). I know that at least in Brandenburg they were offically forced to use the official UTM variants in the future, but they blessed us with these irregular CRS - Brandenburg even gave it an EPSG code! (EPSG:325832 is EPSG:25832 plus the leading 3...)

Well, to solve your problems, add a custom CRS to QGis:

- Name: MV ETRS89 Zone 33:
- Parameter: +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15 +k=0.9996 +x_0=33500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs

Then assigning EPSG 32633 to the LSG layer and assigning this custom CRS to your data layer and enabling on-the-fly projection, they will align. Feel free to save your data layer in an offical CRS... ;)

The ordnance survey of Mecklenburg-Vorpommern are at least so kind as to provide this information on their website: [How to use their freaking CRS](http://www.geoportal-mv.de/land-mv/GeoPortalMV_prod/de/Geowebdienste/_faq/etrs89_zk_gis.jsp)

Comment: Ah... So it was the ordnance survey of Mecklenburg-Vorpommern producing these strange shapefiles with the 33-million metre shift on the x axis. It's always nice to know, what a humdinger. Your solution is more elegant than mine, when the problem arose a couple of weeks ago I got round it by doing an affine transformation. Nick.

Comment: nhopton, your affine transformation basically was reprojecting them, so your solution is as valid as mine. Whatever works, I suppose? :)